# "Dynamics Nav 2017" Why cant you set the visibility of fields on a card?

Tags: dynamics-nav

As far as I know, one can use the visibility attribute of fields on a card page, but they dont work. Why is that?

It is possible to use the attribute for page-parts and for groups, but not for fields no matter if they are inside a group or just on the page.

[page card with tests in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cYs1.png)

[page with bool Show1 = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYohM.png)

[page with bool Show2 = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7xmn.png)

I have the boolean Show1 and Show2 (with the attribute IncludeInDataset = TRUE). Depending on the record, either Show1 is TRUE and Show2 False or the opposite.

1. (In picture 1:) this works for the group. It and all the fields in it are only visible when Show1 is TRUE.
2. (In picture 2,3:) It works for parts. The page parts are only visible when the boolean in their visibility attribute is TRUE.
3. (In picture 4:) Only showing the code works on the page.
   (In picture 5:) If I set the visibility attribute to a variable, the field isn't visibly regardless of whether the variable is TRUE or FALSE.

I know I can still manage the effect of dynamically showing fields by copying the whole group in which the field exists without the specific field, and then hiding and showing the 2 groups to simulate hiding and showing the field. Still, I ask myself, why this workaround needs to be used and thought that someone here at stack-overflow might know.

Is it because of a technical limitation or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

The group is the parental element of the field. When you set the visibilty to false for the group, this property is also applied to the fields in that group.
The other way around, if you set the visibility to true for the group you can hide spicific fields inside that group.
This has something to do with the rendering Dynamics NAV does in the background.
By rendering I mean the application's windows size etc.

But since Dynamics NAV is a blackbox in cases like this I can't tell you more.

Comment: I didnt know about the rendering stuff. When I have the points for the upvote function, I will upvote this, but I am keeping the question open in the hopes that someone who knows the 'blackbox' or the c# code behind it might answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like NAV does not care much about the visibility setting on field level. At least not for dynamic purposes.

If i need to dynamically hide fields i always put that field in an extra group and set the visibility on that group. If you do not specify any name or caption on this extra group it wont be visible at all.